# Why were these two identical spam answers converted to comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

About eleven hours ago, [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/difference-b-w-abstract-and-introduction-writing-for-a-research-paper) received two near-identical answers, from two separate unregistered accounts, that were quite blatant spam. Both were apparently converted to comments by a diamond moderator, and while one has since been deleted, the other is still visible on the linked question as of the time of writing.

As far as I can tell, these shouldn't be comments. They're completely irrelevant to the question, and should have been deleted as spam. I've flagged the surviving comment as no longer needed, but first I'd like to know: **why were these answers converted to comments in the first place?** And if one was then deleted, why wasn't the other one?

Comment: My guess would be the canned review comments that both said "Once you have sufficient reputation you can comment on any post" lead to the assumption that they might be comments and thus the longer one of them was transformed into a comment. Obviously I am not a diamond mod, just an observation for those under 2k rep who can't see the posts. As a side note: In my opinion if people see spam or rude/abusive posts there is no need to leave some canned comments. Flag it as spam or rude/abusive or if you see it in the review queue just press "No comment necessary".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I converted the comments. The two were nearly the same text. I should have deleted one of them, which I've now done.

As for their being spam, they're not advertising any products or services. They're superfluous, yes, and a little bit silly, but that's fine in comments.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I'll chalk this one up to me being a bit too overzealous. Either way, it looks like both comments have been deleted now.